# Is it possible to make ng-repeat delay a bit redrawing of array content

Tags: arrays, angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using ng-repeat to (guess) put array content in table.
Content is drawn dynamically, and it works well, when I'm modifying single elements of an array. But when I reload a whole array, there is this moment, when array is reassigned with new value, and ng-repeat draws blank table (which is actually logically correct). Is there a way to delay redrawing of content that way, the ng-repeat ignores the moment when the array is empty? Like the content is switched to new content without the 'clear' time.

I'm assigning new elements to array this way:

`items = newItems;`

where `items` is the array ng-repeat uses and `newItems` is an array of items freshly downloaded from database. The `newItems` is complete, when the assignment occurres. I'm not doing `items = [];` before the assignemt.

I'm usign angular 1.3

EDIT:

the ng-repeat:

`<tr ng-repeat="order in submittedOrders">`
`stuff`
`<\tr>`

js:

`$scope.reloadView = function() {
        $scope.submittedOrders = OrdersService.getOrdersByStatus(ORDER_STATUS.submitted);

```
};`
```

Can it be the that the table is cleared in the first place, before call to database(service takes data from database) and during the wait, the table is cleared?

Comment: Please provide your code. That will be more helpful.

Comment: plz provide html and js code

Comment: I can provide some code today in the evening. Sorry for incomplete question.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to make use of [Observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables) and [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) of Angular.

Here are few steps you can take:

1. Convert your newItems to a rxjs `Subject`.

   ```
   newItems$ = new Subject();
   ```
2. Whenever you get new values for your array, emit them via subject.

   ```
   this.newItems$.next(newItems);
   ```
3. Make the `items` an observable of `newItems$`, and filter out empty arrays.

   ```
    items = this.newItems$.pipe(
      filter((a:any[]) => {
        return a.length != 0;
      })
    );
   ```
4. In your template, use `async` pipe to iterate over array.

   ```
   *ngFor="item of items | async"
   ```

Below is relevant parts of code that can get you started.

```
import { Observable, of, from, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, mapTo } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

  newItems$ = new Subject();

  items = this.newItems$.pipe(
    filter((a:any[]) => {
      return a.length != 0;
    })
  );

  ...

  // A test method - link it to (click) handler of any div/button in your template
  // This method will emit a non-empty array first, then, after 1 second emit an empty
  // array, and then, after 2 seconds it will emit a non-empty array again with updated 
  // values.
  testMethod() {
    this.newItems$.next([3,4,5]);
    setTimeout((v) => {
        console.log("Emptying the array - should not be displayed browser");
        this.newItems$.next([]);
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout((v) => {
        console.log("Updating the array - should be displayed in browser");
        this.newItems$.next([3,4,4,5]);
    }, 2000);
  }
```

Comment: I think OP asked for angular 1... & your answer is for other versions of angular